# CakePHP - read() losing decimals from MySQL

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

In MySQL I have:

interest_per_day - 0.00076931506849315

But when I use:

```
$variable = $this->InterestRate->find('all', array('InterestRate.interest_type_id' => $interest_type_id));
```

In my $variable interest_per_day is: 0.000769315

How can I manipulate how many decimals I want from DB?
Should I convert it to VARCHAR in DB? Should PHP lose decimals when calculating with decimal?

It's CakePHP 2.2.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the decimal plcaes using mysql cast() function. You can create a virtual field in your Model to get the interest_per_day with some specific decimal places.

```
class InterestRate extends AppModel
{
  ....
  public $virtualFields = array('interest_per_day_precise' => 'cast(interest_per_day as decimal(10,5))');
  ....  
}
```

This will return you one more field named as interest_per_day_precise containing a result with decimal 5 places. 
Hope it worked for you.